# How do I set the default arguments for python functions when not specified?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following method:

```
def validate_parameters(start_date, end_date):

    if(end_date == None):
        end_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

    if(start_date == None):
        start_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
```

I use this values inside my query and then fetch data from DB using my query. How to set this values if the user doesn't specify them in UI? Currently, I set it to the current time, is it good idea/algorithm?

Comment: I do not understand. In your code you already perform check on user-provided dates and set them to current time. What's wrong with it? Could you explain?

Comment: @CaptainTrunky Updated

Answer (score 0):

[The Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) specifies what to do for default arguments. This is the example they provide:

```
def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, reminder='Please try again!'):
while True:
    ok = input(prompt)
    if ok in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
        return True
    if ok in ('n', 'no', 'nop', 'nope'):
        return False
    retries = retries - 1
    if retries < 0:
        raise ValueError('invalid user response')
    print(reminder)
```

It also specifies:

> This function can be called in several ways:
>
> - giving only the mandatory argument: ask_ok('Do you really want to quit?')
> - giving one of the optional arguments: ask_ok('OK to overwrite the file?', 2)
> - or even giving all arguments: ask_ok('OK to overwrite the file?', 2, 'Come on, only yes or no!')

In your case, you'd want to do something like this:

```
def validate_parameters(start_date=None, end_date=None):
```

This will set `start_date` and `end_date` to `None` if no arguments are provided. It'll set `end_date` to None if exactly one argument is provided, and it'll use both as normal if both are provided. Note that the user could provide `None` here themself, which could be a feature.

**EDIT:** It's important to note here as well that the default arguments are only evaluated once, when the function definition is reached. If you try to use something like `def validate_parameters(start_date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()), end_date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))` then these times will only be evaluated once (when the function is *defined,* not when it is *called*) which defeats the point. So don't accidentally fall into that trap.